# HttpErrorResponse status returns 0 instead of actual status in Angular

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, webapi

HttpErrorResponse status returns 0 instead of actual status in angular , but its showing right status on browser network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [CORS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Basically, you're trying to talk to a server and get a response which is not from the same domain as you're on, which your browser thinks is a big 'no-no'.

If you're just developing, you might want to look into a CORS disable plugin (Firefox) or disable web security (Chrome).

Comment: Thank you so much your quick reply. you are correct to disable CORS and its working fine , but every time we cant say to user for disable CORS in browser , so i am finding permanent solution for this.

Comment: @Laxman Normally, the server and the frontend tends to be in the same domain, otherwise you have to serve a cors header in your server response that allows information from all over the web. MDN have a good link on this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: Basically, add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to your response...